# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space --- with intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have the following error when i try to compile my project.

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I added this:
[image]

here:

[image]

I changed this:

[image]

And this although i don't think groovy compiler is not used
[image]

When i run this in terminal:
`java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'heapsize|permsize|threadstacksize'`

I get this (no idea what it means but maybe it helps):
[image]

What is left for me to do?

edit:

I runned:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
long totalMem = rt.totalMemory();
long maxMem = rt.maxMemory();
long freeMem = rt.freeMemory();
double megs = 1048576.0;

System.out.println ("Total Memory: " + totalMem + " (" + (totalMem/megs) + " MiB)");
System.out.println ("Max Memory:   " + maxMem + " (" + (maxMem/megs) + " MiB)");
System.out.println ("Free Memory:  " + freeMem + " (" + (freeMem/megs) + " MiB)");
```

In intelliJ i get:

> Total Memory: 85000192 (81.0625 MiB) 
>   Max Memory:   129957888 (123.9375
>   MiB) Free Memory:  76973192 (73.40735626220703 MiB)

In processing (which has it's own pde) i get:

> Total Memory: 65011712 (62.0 MiB) 
>   Max Memory:   1908932608 (1820.5
>   MiB) Free Memory:  57761176 (55.085350036621094 MiB)

Comment: You get this when you try to **compile** your project?  How many files are in the project?

Comment: I have like 8 files. Not that much. However, i do use blob detection and that takes quite some memory.

Comment: But surely your blob detection happens at run time, not compile time?

Comment: Also i edited my post, the maxMem is around 123mb so something is wrong...

Comment: I guess you will have to create a dump and analysis it.
You can create dump by adding the parameter -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError to your VM lunch configuration.
Then you can analysis it with MAT Analyzer.
http://www.eclipse.org/mat/

Comment: @clankill3r, did any solution work for you? I am having the same problem now.

Comment: @HookUp Can't remember but I improved my blobscanner to consume less memmory.